# how to send/save multiple image from one activity to other?

Tags: android, image, android-camera, sharedpreferences, image-gallery

Suppose i have four or five images whether its from camera or gallery that part i did .Now 
i want to have those four or five images to be in another activity how can i do that,
just as u see in olx  application.
Can anybody help me in this getting me out of this problem.

below this my code :-

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
 String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();

 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
 cursor.close();

 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ImageSharedPref", 0); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
 Editor editor = sp.edit();
 editor.putString("picturePath", picturePath); // Store selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.         
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: just save in application class and then use it from other activity..

Comment: Better save it in file and send the path to the next Activity.

Comment: use Singleton class for this type of work

Comment: how to do that i m not getting BhanuSharma

Comment: as u see in olx just like dat i have to do

Answer (score 0):

Store all images path in a ArrayList> ,pass this list into intent and in your next activity get all image path by using list index.

Comment: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ImageSharedPref", 0); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) 
                {
     editor.putString("images", myList.add(picturePath));
    }

Comment: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ImageSharedPref", 0); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) 
                {
     editor.putString("images", myList.add(picturePath));
    }

Comment: Use sp.getString("key",false). Because you are supplying one value in session don't use loop.

Comment: no actually i store four image-path in array-list n that array list i want to send it other activity through shared preference

Comment: use intent.putExtra("key", arrayList); to pass image into next activity.

Comment: i want to use this images next to next activity so how to do that

Comment: than store all images path into sqlite database(will be better) or pass the same list into next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Save the paths of those image file in the ArrayList.

**Activity A:**

```
ArrayList<Uri> myList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

intent.putExtra("pathList", myList);
```

**Activity B:**

```
ArrayList<Uri> myList = (ArrayList<Uri>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Once you get the list of paths in Activity B you can always access it using the Uri.

To get the Uri of the image selected from the gallery or the camera:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

Comment: could you please explain me how can i save imagepath in arraylist as i m taking image randomly from camera or from gallery

Comment: {
                if (requestCode == 1) 
             {
         
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                myList.add(picturePath);